# How do I recover Windows 10 with files recovered from a drive

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

I had a drive failure about 2 months ago on my custom built PC with Windows 10 (probably professional version).  It was a Seagate drive and they sent the drive to recovery and sent back a USB slimdrive with all of the files recovered.

My question is:  How do I now recover back to Windows 10?

I was hoping I could copy those files onto a new drive and boot up Windows, but that results in "No MBR Found".  I also tried booting from the USB slimdrive, but that results in a different message telling me to select a proper boot device.

Comment: This appears to be off topic here. You may be able to get help on our sister site, [su].

Answer (score 1):

> How do I now recover back to Windows 10?

Download a [fresh Windows Setup-Media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and reinstall windows 10 from there on your new drive. When done, copy *only the files you need* back from the stick to your drive.

Comment: How would the registry be transferred so that all of the programs still work?

Comment: You need to re-install all the programs on top of the freshly installed Windows. The registry contains so much installation-specific information that it is impossible to copy.

Comment: You *could* try to copy your user profile back (\users\name), but I doubt this would make you happy.